# JavaScript plays up until I refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the JS I'm using and it works nicely:

```
$(function() {
    var count = $(".parent a").length;

    $(".parent div").width(function(){
        return ($(".parent").width()/count)-5;
    });

    $(".parent div:not(:last)").css("margin-right","5px");

    $(".parent div:last").width(function() {
        return $(".parent div:last").width() + 5;
    });
  });
```

Only problem is that sometimes when I load the webpage my divs look like this:

[image]

and this is what it looks like after you refresh the page:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it so it loads correct on entering the page?

---

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JpcQA/)

Comment: you should NOT adjust style using JavaScript if you can adjust it using pure CSS

Comment: What browser/OS are you using? Can you reproduce it in different browsers?

Comment: @jasonslyvia Part of the issue with that would be that some browsers targeted may not support the selectors he's using (for instance, "not" or "last"). I would imagine part of the reason for this issue is the order in which the Javascript / CSS / DOM is parsed. If it's cached, that could change.

Comment: @jasonslyvia I'm using JS so it can auto fill the width of the parent div.

Comment: Use media queries and % based widths if you're trying to create a responsive design.

Comment: @lethal-guitar Im using Chrome. It doesn't happen every time I open the page so it's hard to tell if it does it in another browser

Comment: Can you add the html part ? maybe the problem is linked.

Comment: Initially keep hidden the main div (using CSS) after execution of your js code display the div which was hidden...hope it will work for you.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle

Comment: I've tried your fiddle several times (in Firefox), but unfortunately I wasn't able to reproduce the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be better  (with a instead of div)

EDIT: fixed some others css issues:

- need to be display:inline-block;
- .button need to be display:block; (to fill the )

http://jsfiddle.net/JpcQA/4/

```
$(function() {
    var count = $(".parent a").length;

    $(".parent a").width(function(){
        return ($(".parent").width()/(count))-15;
    });

    $(".parent a:not(:last)").css("margin-right","5px");

    $(".parent a:last").width(function() {
        return $(".parent a:last").width() + 5;
    });
});
```

Comment: I just learned we have to be careful with `display:inline-block` because it's not supported by IE6 / 7 (and maybe 8)